# derby error "Subquery is only allowed to return a single column."

Tags: java, jpa, derby, jpql

I got this exception when calling the method that calls this query:

```
SELECT s FROM Survey s 
WHERE s.idsurvey NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT s FROM Useranswer ua 
        JOIN ua.iduser u 
        JOIN ua.idanswer a
        JOIN a.idquestion q
        JOIN q.idsurvey s 
    WHERE 
        ua.iduser.iduser = u.iduser
        AND ua.idanswer.idanswer = a.idanswer
        AND a.idquestion.idquestion = q.idquestion
        AND q.idsurvey.idsurvey = s.idsurvey
        AND u.iduser = :iduser
    )
order by s.dateEnd
```

Any help?
The query seems fine.

Comment: You're declaring the same alias `s` in the top level query (for `Survey`) and in the subquery (for `q.idsurvey`). Perhaps this is causing a problem?

Comment: I saw a few minutes ago that JPA doesn't support subqueries, but i've found another solution using native sql.

Comment: Clearly JPQL does support some subqueries. But then you have "idsurvey IN Collection of Useranswer objects" which makes little sense

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this problem for almost 2 hours.
I've found a solution using native sql.

String query = "select s.IDSURVEY, s.DATE_END from survey s where s.IDSURVEY not IN (select distinct s.IDSURVEY from survey s join question q on s.IDSURVEY = q.IDSURVEY join answer a on q.IDQUESTION = a.IDQUESTION join useranswer ua on a.IDANSWER = ua.IDANSWER where ua.IDUSER = "+iduser+") order by s.DATE_END";

```
return (List<Survey>)em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```